# vim - экспанд слова под курсором

Tags: vim

Чтобы искать по файлу в vim'e, я обычно делаю так:

1. Нажимаю `/`
2. Ввожу требуемый паттерн поиска - например, слово `function`
3. Нажимаю `enter`, и дальше уже двигаюсь по результатам поиска.

Как бы исключить из этого списка пункт2 :)
Допустим, у меня курсор стоит на первой букве слова `function`, требуется комбинация (биндинг в `.vimrc`), которую можно нажать - и слово автоматом добавится в буфер поиска.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Алгоритм следующий:

1. Наводите курсор на слово
2. Нажимаете `*`
3. vim переходит к его следующему вхождению.

Как справедливо отметил **KoVadim**, вместо `*` можно использовать `#`, тогда поиск будет идти в обратном направлении.

Также [тут](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_the_word_under_the_cursor) описан способ по поиску и замене слова под курсором.

Comment: а ещё можно решетку `#`  нажимать. Поиск в противоположном направлении.

Comment: сенкс, то что нужно!

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, добавил в ответ.

Comment: пока что не могу проголосовать за ответ, кармы мало :)

Comment: @o2gy, You're always welcome, как говорится.

Answer (score 3):

Дополнительно. Если нужно перетащить слово под курсором в командную строку (строку поиска), то нужно нажать **Ctrl-R Ctrl-W**

Соответствено, слово под курсором будет в командной строке. Удобно, если делаем какие-нибудь изменения в исходном слове.

Comment: Тоже приятная вещь, спасибо!